TypeScript Confusion - Property 'key' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>
I'm trying to extract the key property by object destructuring, but TypeScript is telling me Property 'key' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>
despite the fact that when I console.log(props), I get the following:
{
  "key": "Miami, FL, USA",
  "tabIndex": -1,
  "role": "option",
  "id": "location-input-option-0",
  "data-option-index": 0,
  "aria-disabled": false,
  "aria-selected": false,
  "className": "MuiAutocomplete-option"
}

renderOption={(props, option) => {
  console.log("renderOption props:", props);
  const { key } = props;

  const matches =
    option.structured_formatting.main_text_matched_substrings || [];

  const parts = parse(
    option.structured_formatting.main_text,
    matches.map((match: any) => [
      match.offset,
      match.offset + match.length,
    ]),
  );

  return (
    <li {...props}>
      <Grid container alignItems="center">
        <Grid item sx={{ display: "flex", width: 44 }}>
          <LocationOnIcon sx={{ color: "text.secondary" }} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          sx={{ width: "calc(100% - 44px)", wordWrap: "break-word" }}
        >
          {parts.map((part, index) => (
            <Box
              key={index}
              component="span"
              sx={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? "bold" : "regular" }}
            >
              {part.text}
            </Box>
          ))}
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            {option.structured_formatting.secondary_text}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </li>
  );
}


This is simply because the properties key, as well as data-option-index, are not in the type of HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>. To access these additional properties type safe, you need to add them to the type definition.
props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement> & {key: string, "data-option-index": number}

In your case i would use something like that:
type RenderOptionProps = {
    props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement> & {key: string, "data-option-index": number};
    option: any; // better choose something else
}
const renderOption= ({props, option}: RenderOptionProps) => {...}

